# Add players to a list with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-applications

I'm new at AngularJS. I do know some javascript, but AngularJS seems hard to learn (maybe it's just me).

My problem is as follows...

I have a list of players and I would like to make it possible for a user (coach or whoever) to add their players to the list. I have tried couple of method for these past few days, and I just can't figure it out.

Code is below, and u can check out my plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjB7oqbzGWqYRRMdXh5z):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MoveCtrl" class = "container">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-4 left-space"> 


<!--Forgot to add this block of code for input-->
    <label>Player name: </label> <input #playerName/>
    <button (click) = "add(playerName.value); playerName.value = ''">
    Add
    </button>
<!--Rest is the same-->

        <label class="left-space-title" for="aplayers">Available Players</label>                                
        <select class="left-space-container" size="5" multiple ng-model="available" 
        ng-options="player as player.name for player in availableplayers">
        </select>         

    </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-2 mid-space ">

        <input id="moveright" type="button" value=">>" 
        ng-click="moveItem(available, availableplayers,selectedplayers)" />

        <input id="moveleft" type="button" value="<<" 
        ng-click="moveItem(selected, selectedplayers,availableplayers)" />    

    </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-4 right-space">

        <label class="right-space-title" for="splayers">Selected Players</label>                                                    
        <select class="right-space-container" size="5" multiple ng-model="selected" 
        ng-options="player as player.name for player in selectedplayers">
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.mid-space {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-space__title,
.right-space__title {
  width: 100%;
}

.left-space-container,
.right-space-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#moveright,
#moveleft {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MoveCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.moveItem = function(items, from, to) {
        items.forEach(function(item) {
          var idx = from.indexOf(item);
          if (idx != -1) {
              from.splice(idx, 1);
              to.push(item);      
          }
        });
    };        

    $scope.selectedplayers = [];                                

    $scope.availableplayers = [
      {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'foo'
      }, 
      {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'boo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'goo'
      }
    ];
  });
```

Plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjB7oqbzGWqYRRMdXh5z) if you would like to fiddle with the code directly

Comment: I see plunker is working fine. Could you explain more about your problem

Comment: Your plunker works, what exactly you want to achieve, can you clarify?

Comment: I added wrong version of the file, I updated the code and plunkr with an input box and a button. 

I would just like to figure out a way for a user to add their own players to the left column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plunker has been updated with your working code changes to add the new player to the available players list

[add new player plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zp8xwgJpyXEFRPoaJ5W?p=preview)

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
      var numberOfplayers = $scope.availableplayers.length;
      var newPlayer = {
          id : numberOfplayers + 1,
          name : $scope.newPlayerName
      }

      console.log($scope.newPlayerName);
      $scope.availableplayers.push(newPlayer);
    }

<label>Player name: </label> <input ng-model="newPlayerName"/>
        <button ng-click = "addItem(playerName);">
        Add
        </button>
```

code changes done .

1.set the ng-model for the input field . 
2.get the value of the
    input fiend in controllers add player method. 
3.create the new
    players object with the generated id value. 
4.Insert the new player
    object to the availableplayers scope variable which inturn pops up
    the value in the box.

Comment: Thank you Robert... I couldn't have figured this out by myself...  +1